# Cochran's Q test with changing proportions

Tags: spss, proportion, cochran-q

for my thesis I am investigating the change in proportions of children in regular and special education. The information is obtained through an online questionnaire, and I have data for 4 consecutive years.

The frequencies, and the proportion regular educations are as such:

Year 1: Reg 462 Spec 607 Prop: 0.762

Year 2: Reg 194 Spec 343 Prop: 0.566

Year 3: Reg 131 Spec 231 Prop: 0.567

Year 4: Reg 120 Spec 197 Prop: 0.609

As you can see, there is a big difference in numbers when comparing the first year to the following years. When I want to perform a Cochran’s Q test (because of the every year-element) to compare these proportions, it will only take 161 people into account, because those 161 are the only ones that participated in all 4 years, and there is no significant difference in proportions found.

My question: is there a possibility to see if the proportions differ significantly without filtering out all the missing data? Is it possible that SPSS checks if there is a difference in proportions by using all the data per year? It seems like such a waste to not take all the information into account.

Comment: Use the logistic regression with child specific random intercept.

Comment: 161 people ?  Howdo you compute.

Comment: This question is vague and perhaps not amenable to conduct an Edit.